# Download PDF of page using print CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am look to create a button. When clicked the page will create a PDF using the print styles I have defined via CSS. Is there a way to do this via a jquery? I have attempted to do this with jsPDF but it requires me to define my own styles.